# Airflow Architecture for Microservices

Tags: python, architecture, microservices, etl, airflow

My current platform architecture has a microservice for downloading/collecting data, a microservice for ETL and another microservice to process some complex SQL scripts.

I want to use Airflow to schedule and monitor workflows. I tried it and it worked very nice. However, I have to put all functionalities as tasks into one container of Airflow; and this doesn't follow current microservice architecture. What I wanted is to use Airflow as a scheduler and communicate with other microservices.

I want to ask:
**What is the best way to use Airflow with microservices? Should I use tasks in DAGs to communicate with microservices (publish messages and microservices will subscribe)?**

DAG can be described as below. Please note that there're other tasks like validation after downloading data but I've just simplified it.
[DAG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3i4ff.png)

Comment: Can you expound on your "However, I have to put all functionalities as tasks into one container of Airflow; and this doesn't follow current microservice architecture." comment as to _how_ specifically you view it doesn't fit in such an architecture?

Comment: Hi @joeb, if I gather all functionalities of those microservices into one under airflow container, that would be monolithic. What I want to do is having Airflow as a scheduler while keeping all microservices as they are now. I've read few articles but I haven't found an answer for this question (E.g: https://eng.lyft.com/running-apache-airflow-at-lyft-6e53bb8fccff or https://www.astronomer.io/blog/airflow-infrastructure/). What do you think?

Comment: What did you end up doing? We have similar issue @Whiskey

Answer (score 4):

A workflow engine like Apache Airflow and an architectural paradigm like microservices are inherently antithetical. Both are perfectly legitimate, both valuable, and both have pros & cons, but they are two completely different approaches to building distributed systems.

You hit on it yourself in your comment:

> ..if I gather all functionalities of those microservices into one under airflow container, that would be monolithic.

The microservices principle being violated here is referred to as "[smart endpoints, dumb pipes](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html#SmartEndpointsAndDumbPipes)".

The idea being 'Smart Microservice A' should communicate with 'Smart Microservice B' (be that directly or indirectly) and that you should not have 'Dumb Microsevice A' and 'Dumb Microservice B' wired together by 'Smart Workflow Service'.

The latter is more of an [Enterprise Service Bus (ESB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus) or a [Service Oriented Architecture (SOA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) design.

Again, ESBs and SOAs have their place, but a microservices architecture is a different kind of architecture and is inherently incompatible.

Comment: Thank-you for explaining things, can you refer some tool like airflow which can help in this scenario, where we want to keep the microservice architecture but want to be able to do all(most) things airflow help us, like DAGs and has built in monitoring logging retries etc etc.

Comment: I think you'll want to look to frameworks and general best practices.